# How do I send mail consisting of sqlquery results - but only sending if certain users run?

Tags: sendmail

I'm trying to run a command to send the results of sqlplus query in an email but only if certain users set the command to run - not the dev team.

Something like:

(emailwhenran)

```
sqlplus username/pwd@instance  
SPOOL /home/sadmin/sqlmail/spool.out  
set linesize 2000  
set wrap off  
@/home/sadmin/sqlmail/query.sql  
SPOOL OFF  
exit  
mail -s "Subject" email@address.com < /home/sadmin/sqlmail/spool.out
```

What would I have to add to have it send only if a certain user runs my emailwhenran command?

Thank you.

Comment: Not clear if you want to enable certain user(s) or to disable a certain group (dev). Try the `id` command.

Comment: I want all users to be able to run it.

so,
Dev1, dev2, guest1, admin1 are my users.

Only if f guest1 runs the command, I want an email sent out.

Comment: OK, try `id -u`.